# make 3D input for kmeans clustering

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to use K-means clustering with data with these characteristics:
I have about 1900 samples. for a specific resolution with a specific bitrate, we have a PSNR value. now the question is about the input format for K-means clustering. how do I make the input data for k-means clustering? because each input has 6 values for each bitrate(from 1MB to 6MB)and so for two resolutions we have another 6 values. now my question is how do I make the input sample for K-means? because K-means input is a two-dimensional array.
I have two arrays one shows the PSNR values for different bitrates( I have 6 bitrates and the index of column means the related bitrate) the first array is for resolution 720 and the second is for resolution 1080:

```
psnr_bitrate_720=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'E:/720/*.txt')])
psnr_bitrate_1080=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'E:/1080/*.txt')])
```

the `psnr_bitrate_720` contains PSNR values for different bitrate and each row is a sample:

```
24.800833 26.259667 27.867333 28.905833 30.101833 31.333167
26.911167 31.013500 33.899667 35.443500 37.052167 39.330167
29.643833 34.168000 36.879667 39.127000 40.843000 42.662167
28.843000 33.450500 36.487667 38.876333 40.845167 42.678833
27.565500 31.669500 34.501833 36.872833 38.813333 40.377667
30.499000 34.954500 37.961000 40.144833 41.881333 43.772667
29.600000 33.780000 36.563333 38.752333 40.518333 42.643167
```

I used it as input into K-means clustering before. now I want to consider another resolution that means 1080 too and as an input to K-means clustering, I have 3 dimensions.
for this I used this:

```
c = np.dstack((psnr_bitrate_1080, psnr_bitrate_720))
c2 = np.swapaxes(c, 1, 2)
```

but it said the Kmeans accepts 2D input, not 3D. now my question is that how do I consider 3d as input and my assumption is true and Kmeans can cluster 3D data?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions/answers.  Your question is more about applying an algorithm.  FYI, the input need not be two-dimensional (see [scikit-learn iris example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html))

Comment: this is not true. the input to Kmeans in the above example that you said, has 2 dimensions. each row is a sample and each column is a feature value but in my question, I have three different value resolutions, PSNR, and a bitrate that for each (PSNR, bitrate, resolution) we have a value. so my question is different

Comment: You've shown no code and no data... not a recipe for program understanding. Why can't your input have three columns, resolution, bit rate, and PSNR?

Comment: I added extra information to my quesion. please consider them.

Comment: How about adding a column for the resolution?  Then you could have one 2D array with all the info.